# How to compare a string null laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following problems !

I recieve the information from the form

```
public function crearcomentario ()
{
    $blogId = \Request::input('identificador');  
    $autor = \Request::input('autor');  
    $correo = \Request::input('correo');  
    $content = \Request::input('content');
    $find = User::where('username','=',$autor)->get();
    $buscar = $find->toArray();
    $comentarios = new Comentario();
    //$comentarios->autor_id = $buscar[0]["id"];
    $comentarios->correo = $correo;
    $comentarios->articulo_id = $blogId;
    $comentarios->contenido = $content;
    echo $find;
    echo $autor;        
    //$comentarios->save();
}
```

The variable `$find` return the information about user introduce in the form.

My question is how can I compare if the user find is empty [] ? I try to use

```
if(is_null($find))
```

but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$find` would be a Laravel [Collection](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections). You can use the [`isEmpty()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-isempty) function to check whether it is empty:

```
if($find->isEmpty()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
$find = User::where('username','=',$autor)->get();

if($find) {...}
```